# How do I achieve on scroll behavior where both the toolbar and bottom navigation should hide?Only one of them is working

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to achieve the coordinator layout behaviour where on scrolling the recycler view can hide both the toolbar and bottom navigation view. So far I have achieved one success i.e bottom navigation bottom bar does hide but with one caveat that it remains active even when the keyboard is on(how do I fix that too?)
My main concern here is how do I achieve the same feature of bottom navigation view of hiding into the toolbar?

I have included the custom toolbar in Appbar layout, but I have tried to add the Toolbar layout tag too in the AppBar nothing works, It just remains the same.
And for the bottomnavigation jumping up on top I don't know what to do? till now I have added `snap` scroll flags on the bottomnavigation view to stop this behaviour and also snap flag didn't work, I think so, coz it remains in halfway position while going up on search tap.
Got this BottomNavigationBehavior from the wonderful article.

[reference](https://android.jlelse.eu/scroll-your-bottom-navigation-view-away-with-10-lines-of-code-346f1ed40e9e)

[video showing behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4nIG.jpg)

[image for snap behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0tvF.jpg)

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
        <include
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                layout="@layout/browser_search_tap_tb"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/browser_tb"

        />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    <!--Scrolling effect for the bottom nav menu-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:listitem="@layout/rv_test_items"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/rv_test"
    />
    <!--Bottom navigation view for the Selection of the Tabs and Items in Menu-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:id="@+id/browser_bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ffff"
            app:layout_behavior="com.example.android.browserui.BottomNavigationBehavior"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**browser_search_tap_tb.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        app:contentInsetStart="8dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="8dp"
>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="Search or type new address"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="12dp"
                android:paddingStart="12dp"
                android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_mic"
                android:inputType="textWebEditText"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_et_search"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:id="@+id/et_search_bar_tap"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

**BottomNavigationBehavior.kt**

```kotlin
class BottomNavigationBehavior<V : View>(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
    CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>(context, attrs) {

    private var lastStartedType: Int = 0

    private var offsetAnimator: ValueAnimator? = null

    var isSnappingEnabled = false

    override fun layoutDependsOn(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, dependency: View): Boolean {
        if (dependency is Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
            updateSnackbar(child, dependency)
        }
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency)
    }

    override fun onStartNestedScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, directTargetChild: View, target: View, axes: Int, type: Int
    ): Boolean {
        if (axes != ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL)
            return false

        lastStartedType = type

        offsetAnimator?.cancel()

        return true
    }

    override fun onNestedPreScroll(
        coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, target: View, dx: Int, dy: Int, consumed: IntArray, type: Int
    ) {
        super.onNestedPreScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dx, dy, consumed, type)
        child.translationY = max(0f, min(child.height.toFloat(), child.translationY + dy))
    }

    override fun onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, target: View, type: Int) {
        if (!isSnappingEnabled)
            return

        // add snap behaviour
        // Logic here borrowed from AppBarLayout onStopNestedScroll code
        if (lastStartedType == ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH || type == ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH) {
            // find nearest seam
            val currTranslation = child.translationY
            val childHalfHeight = child.height * 0.5f

            // translate down
            if (currTranslation >= childHalfHeight) {
                animateBarVisibility(child, isVisible = false)
            }
            // translate up
            else {
                animateBarVisibility(child, isVisible = true)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun animateBarVisibility(child: View, isVisible: Boolean) {
        if (offsetAnimator == null) {
            offsetAnimator = ValueAnimator().apply {
                interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
                duration = 150L
            }

            offsetAnimator?.addUpdateListener {
                child.translationY = it.animatedValue as Float
            }
        } else {
            offsetAnimator?.cancel()
        }

        val targetTranslation = if (isVisible) 0f else child.height.toFloat()
        offsetAnimator?.setFloatValues(child.translationY, targetTranslation)
        offsetAnimator?.start()
    }

    private fun updateSnackbar(child: View, snackbarLayout: Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
        if (snackbarLayout.layoutParams is CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            val params = snackbarLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

            params.anchorId = child.id
            params.anchorGravity = Gravity.TOP
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
            snackbarLayout.layoutParams = params
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally Resolved My issue after getting my head around for 4 days here are some changes which I did and solved the issues :
**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"<!--Removed this line-->
    >


<!--Bottom navigation view for the Selection of the Tabs and Items in Menu-->
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"<!--Removed this line-->
            android:id="@+id/browser_bottom_nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ffff"
            app:layout_behavior="com.example.android.browserui.BottomNavigationBehavior"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    />
```

Here in activity_main.xml, I removed the layout_behavior because the appbar itself is invoking the scroll behavior for other layout items, it acts as a parent.

> **app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"**

Also removed scrollflags from the bottom navigation view, AS I was implementing this behavior from the Class BottomNavigationBehavior.kt, You find the implementation below

> **app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"**

**browser_search_tap_tb.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" <!--Removed this line-->
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
        app:contentInsetStart="8dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="8dp"
>
```

Here in browser_search_tb, I removed the following line because it was overriding the Scrollflags in co-ordinator layout so removed it and it worked flawlessly

> **app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"**

**BottomNavigationBehavior.kt**

```kotlin
override fun onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, target: View, type: Int) {
        if (!isSnappingEnabled)
           return // removed this line
{
        // add snap behaviour
        // Logic here borrowed from AppBarLayout onStopNestedScroll code
        if (lastStartedType == ViewCompat.TYPE_TOUCH || type == ViewCompat.TYPE_NON_TOUCH) {
            // find nearest seam
            val currTranslation = child.translationY
            val childHalfHeight = child.height * 0.5f

            // translate down
            if (currTranslation >= childHalfHeight) {
                animateBarVisibility(child, isVisible = false)
            }
            // translate up
            else {
                animateBarVisibility(child, isVisible = true)
            }
        }
}
}
```

Here I removed the

> **return**

and added braces{} to the if statement and snap feature did work properly

Hope this answer will help you and will cut down your debugging time.
The above reference is one of the best article you can find for scrolling behavior on the internet it simple and smooth to grasp

Comment: you know your code the best but we don't. would be better if you just added the final xml solution to hide both toolbar and bottom nav.